# Division of Integers as Double in Scala

Tags: scala, integer, double

I have a file with information about the age of people and the number of friends they have. I'm using Spark RDD's and Scala to calculate the average number of friends by age like this:

```
    val friendsByAge: Array[(Int, Double)] = (
      actualData
      .mapValues((value: Int) => {(value, 1)})
      .reduceByKey((acc: (Int, Int), value: (Int, Int)) => (acc._1 + value._1, acc._2 + value._2))
      .mapValues((tuple: (Int, Int)) => tuple._1.toDouble / tuple._2)
      .collect()
    )
```

This works. However, if I remove the `tuple._1.toDouble` conversion from the last step (where I'm dividing two integers) I get the following error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Array[(Int, Int)]
 required: Array[(Int, Double)]
```

I thought that, when dividing two integers, if I type that the result is `Double` it should return a double. If this is not the case, why is this simple code returning a double when I divide two integers?

```
scala> val a: Double = 10/5
val a: Double = 2.0

scala> println(a)
2.0

scala> println(10/5)
2
```

In summary, I know how to solve it using `tuple._1.toDouble` but I want to know what's going on. I'm new to Scala and I have a Python background so I feel like understanding the basic concepts is key. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Int` can be casted to `Double` automatically but `(Int, Int)` is not automatically casted to `(Double, Double)`. Not sure of the exact rules but I think only primitive types support casting (without an explicit/implicit conversion rule).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let's dig a bit more on the provided code

```scala
scala> val a: Double = 10/5
val a: Double = 2.0

scala> println(a)
2.0

scala> println(10/5)
2
```

The first one, looks like it solves the problem, but it is not exactly correct. If you do `10 / 3` the result will not be the expected one

```scala
scala> val a: Double = 10 / 3
val a: Double = 3.0

scala> val a: Double = 10.toDouble / 3
val a: Double = 3.3333333333333335

scala> val a: Double = 10 / 3.toDouble
val a: Double = 3.3333333333333335
```

So, when you write a number in scala, the compiler will infer that is an [Int](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Int.html) (Unless you add a type).

```scala
val a = 1          // infers Int
val b = 1: Double  // 1 is converted to Double and then `b` infers Double
val c: Double = 1  // 1 is infered as Int and then cast as Double
```

If you look at the signatures of the method `/` from `Int` class you will see

```scala
  def /(x: Byte): Int
  def /(x: Short): Int
  def /(x: Char): Int
  def /(x: Int): Int
  def /(x: Long): Long
  def /(x: Float): Float
  def /(x: Double): Double
```

So, the **method** says what is the **return type**. Remember also that in scala [everything is an object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html) and [every value has a type](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html). You can also take a look at [how operators work in scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/operators.html)